# pgfplots 3d cylindrical coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I am trying to plot a cylindrical coordinate system using `pgfplots`. The idea would be to plot the `r,theta` plane similar to what `polaraxis` provides, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvhAO.png). I don't know how to translate something like this into a 3D environment.

Is there an easy way to plot a custom coordinate system within the current 3D axis?

**UPDATE**: I may not have been precise enough. I am specifically interested in plotting the coordinate/axis system, i.e. the `r,theta` grid in a 3D plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `data cs` key to set the coordinate system in which the data is interpreted. This works perfectly fine for 3D plots as well, supplying a third coordinate automatically acts as a cylindrical projection. See also section *4.24 Transforming Coordinate Systems* of the `pgfplots` manual (v1.10).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot3+[data cs=polarrad,domain=0:2*pi] (\x,1,2*\x);
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update:** Added a faked 3D `polaraxis`, this could definitely use some improvement, but might get you started. A better solution would apply the style of the "polar axis" somewhat nicer, and currently the labels are clipped, also the radius is fixed, that should probably be somehow dependent on the plotted data, but I don't have time to delve into this that deep at the moment.

I also changed the `data cs` to `polar` because I didn't get the `foreach \thet` to work with fractions of `pi`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      axis x line=middle,
      axis y line=middle,
      axis z line=middle,
      ytick=\empty,
      data cs=polar,
      ]
      \foreach \r in {0,0.25,...,1.25} {
        \addplot+[domain=0:360,mark=none,black,samples=200, smooth] (\x, \r);
      }
      \foreach \thet in {0,30,...,330} {
        % some trickery to get the label expanded
        \edef\doplot{\noexpand\addplot+[domain=0:1.3,mark=none,black] (\thet, \noexpand\x) node[pos=1.2]  {\thet};}
        \doplot
      }
      \addplot3+[domain=0:360] (\x,1,2*\x);
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although I was not aware of the `data cs` key, I have clarified my question above. Yet, I will make use of `data cs`!

Comment: @Markus I added some code that perhaps gets you started on a 3D polar axes system :)

Comment: This works nicely. Is it possible to plot the `cs` in a different plane than `x,y`? I can manipulate the view to get what I want, yet it could make things a bit easier...

Comment: You mean you want the `polaraxis` at an arbitrary `z` height? That could simply be accomplished by changing the `\addplot` commands to `\addplot3` and add a `z` component. Or do you want the `polaraxis` at an angle with `x,y`? In that case you'll have to do some math to calculate the coordinates, but it should be possible to do so. If you simply want to look at the plot from a different angle you could also try the `view` option to the `axis` environment.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272884/120853), one can supply `y domain=0:0` to specify a _line plot_ instead of a mesh. This gets rid of the 'back connection' from the end back to the start of the plot, see [here](https://imgur.com/gbMv8Mf.jpg).

Answer (score 4):

run with `xelatex` or `latex`->`dvisps`->`ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-1)(3,4)
\psset{lightsrc=80 10 30,viewpoint=100 20 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=50}
\defFunction[algebraic]{FIII}(t)
   {t^1.1*sin(15*t)}
   {t^1.1*cos(15*t)}
   {1.5*t}
\psSolid[object=courbe,range=0 4,ngrid=360 6,function=FIII,hue=0.2 0.3,linewidth=0.1pt,r=0.1]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do like the `pstricks` style, but would rather stay within `tikz/pgfplots`. I have updated the question above as well.